# PHP: Apply Chmod during Unarchiving

Tags: php, upload, zip, archive, chmod

This is what I've got so far. I need to be able to apply 0666 to all the files in the archive. Can't I do that as I am exporting? What is a sample code for changing the chmod during unarchiving or after unarchiving?

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('upload/'. $username . $file_ext) === TRUE) {
$zip->extractTo('dir/' . $username);
$zip->close();
} else {
echo 'failed';
}
```

Thanks for all of the help!
Brandon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `0666` on directories might not be what you want ;-)

File creation in any process in Linux will use with `0777` for directories and `0666` for files **but** it depends on the `umask` value what the final permissions will be. By default the `umask` value is `0022` which creates files like `0644`; it works like a subtraction.

So by resetting the `umask` to 0 you probably get what you need.

```
umask(0);
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('upload/'. $username . $file_ext) === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('dir/' . $username);
    $zip->close();
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: I added that before the unarchiving script and the permissions on the server are sill 0604. Im using this with an API so I need to give it access to transfer files to their service...

Comment: Should I try umask(111); or something like that?

Comment: If `umask(0)` doesn't work, changing the value won't make much sense. I don't have the `zip` extension on my machine (because it won't compile) so I've only tested it by a simple `touch('testfile')` and that behaves properly when changing the `umask`.

Comment: Managed to compile the zip extension and my suggestion works to change the permissions on extraction. Updated my answer to reflect the code that worked for me.

Comment: I did that exact thing. But for some reason it wasn't working. However, I found out that I was using chmod() wrong. I have chmod(dir/dir) instead of chmod(/dir/dir) :)